# making new pandas columns based on min and max values

Tags: python, pandas

given this data frame:

```
    HOUSEID     PERSONID    STRTTIME    ENDTIME TDTRPNUM
0   20000017    1            955          1020     1
1   20000017    1           1130          1132     2
2   20000017    1           1330          1400     3
3   20000017    2            958          1020     1
4   20000017    2           1022          1025     2
5   20000017    2           1120          1122     3
6   20000017    2           1130          1132     4
```

I want to make 2 new columns `firsttrip_time` and `lasttrip_time`. Then, add `STRTTIME` to the `firsttrip_time` for minimum number of `TDTRPNUM` , And add `ENDTIME`    to `lasttrip_time` for the maximum number of `TDTRPNUM` in each `HOUSEID` and `PERSONID` category.

results:

```
    HOUSEID     PERSONID    firsttrip_time  lasttrip_time   
0   20000017      1          955              1400             
1   20000017      2          958              1132
```

I have tried this to get the mix and max, but have no idea how to continue the process?

```
grouped = df.groupby(['HOUSEID', 'PERSONID','STRTTIME', 'ENDTIME'])['TDTRPNUM']
max = grouped.max()
min = grouped.min()
```

Can you help me with this or give me a hint?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `agg`, and finally `rename` your columns:

```
print (df.sort_values(["HOUSEID","PERSONID","TDTRPNUM"])
         .groupby(["HOUSEID", "PERSONID"], as_index=False)
         .agg({"STRTTIME":"first","ENDTIME":"last"})
         .rename(columns={"STRTTIME":"firsttrip_time","ENDTIME":"lasttrip_time"}))

    HOUSEID  PERSONID  firsttrip_time  lasttrip_time
0  20000017         1             955           1400
1  20000017         2             958           1132
```

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid `groupby` by first `sort_values` by TDTRPNUM and then use `drop_duplicates` with once first with the STRTTIME to get the row with min TDTRPNUM and once last with ENDTIME to get the row with max TDTRPNUM, `merge` both and `rename` to get the expected output

```
df_ = df.sort_values('TDTRPNUM')
res = (df_.drop_duplicates(['HOUSEID','PERSONID'], keep='first')
          [['HOUSEID','PERSONID', 'STRTTIME']]\
          .merge(df_.drop_duplicates(['HOUSEID','PERSONID'], keep='last')
                    [['HOUSEID','PERSONID', 'ENDTIME']])\
          .rename(columns={'STRTTIME':'firsttrip_time', 
                           'ENDTIME':'lasttrip_time'})
      )
print(res)
    HOUSEID  PERSONID  firsttrip_time  lasttrip_time
0  20000017         1             955           1400
1  20000017         2             958           1132
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this option:

```
aggFunc = {'STRTTIME':['min'], 'ENDTIME':['max']}
df = df.groupby(['HOUSEID','PERSONID']).agg(aggFunc).reset_index()
print(df)
```